# Animating a drop shadow for a group of elements one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I would like to make it a bit more obvious that the elements on the page are clickable.

To do this, when the page loads, I would like to loop through them and have the drop shadow show for about a second or so, then revert it to its original state and move on to the next.  I only want to loop the elements once.

This is my current attempt, but I'm sure its not threaded right.  I think it just delays the load of page.  It just attempts to change the css class for the element for 2 seconds, then sets it back.

```
function animateBarGraph() {
    var elements = $(".element");
    elements.each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'class': 'dropShadowClass'
        }).delay(2000);
        $(this).css("class", "element");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two parameters here: one is the `step` (duration between activating two elements) and `duration` (between start of rise and start of fall on one particular element).

Play with `step` and `duration` till you like the result. The *actual duration* of rise and fall are set in the `box-shadow` `transition` (CSS: the `.6s`).

If you make `duration` param shorter than the actual CSS duration, it will begin the descend before finishing the rise. Might look weird.

I added the rise/fall effect to hover, too. It seems more natural.

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $custAnim = {
        'step': 300,
        'duration': 600,
        'animateBarGraphElement': function (elem) {
            elem.addClass('animated');
            setTimeout(function() {
                elem.removeClass('animated');
            }, $custAnim.duration
            );
        },
        'animateBarGraph': function (i) {
            var elements = $(".element");
            if (elements.length > i) {
                $custAnim.animateBarGraphElement(elements.eq(i));
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $custAnim.animateBarGraph(i + 1);
                }, $custAnim.step);
            }
        }
    };
    $custAnim.animateBarGraph(0);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
button, .element {cursor: pointer;}
.element {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    transition: box-shadow .6s ease;
}
.element.animated, .element:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 14px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="$custAnim.animateBarGraph(0)">Run again</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`delay` is the worst choice for that, personally I would play with css animation where you can set how many times it has to perform (1 in this case) and animation delay. But since time is money I crafted something like that on my knee, hope you find it useful:

```
function addShadow(elm){$(elm).addClass('shadow'); console.log(elm)}
function removeShadow(elm){$(elm).removeClass('shadow')}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elements = $("a, button");
    var duration = 1000;
    $.each(elements, function(i, elm) {
        window.setTimeout(addShadow, i*duration, elm);
        window.setTimeout(removeShadow, (i*duration + duration), elm);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcvbc82x/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin. I used all my imagination inventing a name for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.element').ripple('dropShadowClass', 2000);
});

(function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.ripple = function(cssClass, mills) {
        var delay = 0;
        return this.each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $self.addClass(cssClass);
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $self.removeClass(cssClass);
                }, mills);
            }, delay);
            delay += mills;
        });
    };
 
}( jQuery ));
```

```css
.dropShadowClass {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  <a href="#" class="element">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="element">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="element">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="element">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```